# Docker commit not working

Tags: docker, commit

I have lucid:latest image with Ubuntu 10.04. After run this image I'm trying to change host name:

```
docker run -t -i lucid:latest /bin/bash
```

After changing hostname in another console window I'm typing commands:

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
fdab6a995726        lucid:latest       "/bin/bash"         4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds                            furious_stallman 
$ sudo docker commit fdab6a995726
```

After that my changes that I make to this image should be saved but is not. If I logout from container and back again changes are not commited. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you should try `docker commit fdab6a995726 IMAGENAME` with IMAGENAME the name you want to give your image (free to choose).
also there is usually no need to write `sudo docker`, just `docker commit ID IMAGENAME` or `docker commit CONTAINERNAME IMAGENAME` (containername can be set when using "--name CONTAINERNAME" in run-command (for example `docker run -t -i --name test lucid:latest /bin/bash`)